# Upgraded rbenv and still can't install ruby 2.4.0

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am trying to install ruby 2.4.0 using rbenv.

I am using homebrew.

When I tried the following command:

```
rbenv install ruby 2.4.0
```

I get the following:

```
ruby-build: definition not found: 2.4.0

The following versions contain `2.4.0' in the name:
  2.4.0-dev
  2.4.0-preview1
  rbx-2.4.0

See all available versions with `rbenv install --list'.

If the version you need is missing, try upgrading ruby-build:

  brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build
```

I performed the brew update and brew upgrade ruby-build commands and I still get the same message that ruby-build definition 2.4.0 not found.

How can I install ruby 2.4.0 and fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that I had to do the following:

```
brew reinstall ruby-build --HEAD
```

then I was able to install ruby 2.4.0 using:

```
rbenv install 2.4.0
```

I'm guessing that  brew upgrade ruby-build --HEAD did not update the latest ruby installations available.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking *Ruby*'s version through:

```
ruby -v
```

If it's not the version you need, make sure you download it from their [Official Website](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).

Then, if you already have *Homebrew* installed, you can try the following command:

```
brew install ruby
```

Otherwise, you can install *Homebrew* first through this command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: when I do brew install ruby it tells me that ruby 2.4.0 is already installed.

Comment: It should be installed then, try ruby -v to double check.